# jquery animate issue accordion slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-animate

i am using the following code to simulate an accordion slider.
it works fine.
the only issue i have, is that i can't move properly from the 1st block to the second (i jump directly to the 3rd) and from the 4th to the 3rd (i jump directly to the 2nd).
any ideas on how to contain it????

html

```
<div id="slider1">
</div><!--slider1 end -->
<div id="slider2">
</div><!--slider2 end -->
<div id="slider3">
</div><!--slider3 end -->
<div id="slider4">
</div><!--slider4 end -->
```

css

```
#slider1 {
        width:238px;
        border-left:1px solid #000;
        border-right:1px solid #FFF;
        border-top:1px solid #000;
        border-bottom:1px solid #000;;
        height:398px;
        overflow:hidden;
        float:left;
        box-shadow: inset -35px 0 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        background-image:url(../images/slider1.jpg);
    }

    #slider1:hover {
            background-image:url(../images/slider1_hover.jpg);

}

        #slider2 {
        width:238px;
            border-left:1px solid #000;
        border-right:1px solid #FFF;
        border-top:1px solid #000;
        border-bottom:1px solid #000;;
        height:398px;
        overflow:hidden;
                float:left;
        /*box-shadow: inset -45px 0 5px -5px hsla(0,0%,0%,.25);*/
        box-shadow: inset -45px 0 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        background-image:url(../images/slider2.jpg);
    }

        #slider2:hover {
            background-image:url(../images/slider2_hover.jpg);
}
        #slider3 {
        width:238px;
            border-left:1px solid #000;
        border-right:1px solid #FFF;
        border-top:1px solid #000;
        border-bottom:1px solid #000;;
        height:398px;
        overflow:hidden;
                float:left;
        box-shadow: inset -45px 0 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        background-image:url(../images/slider3.jpg);
    }

        #slider3:hover {
            background-image:url(../images/slider3_hover.jpg);
}
        #slider4 {
        width:238px;
            border-left:1px solid #000;
        border-right:1px solid #000;
        border-top:1px solid #000;
        border-bottom:1px solid #000;;
        height:398px;
        overflow:hidden;
                float:left;
        box-shadow: inset -45px 0 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        background-image:url(../images/slider4.jpg);

    }

        #slider4:hover {
            background-image:url(../images/slider4_hover.jpg);
}
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#slider1").hover(
    //on mouseover
    function() {

        $(this).stop(false, true).animate({  
        width: '+=412' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow

      );
      $(slider2).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '-=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider3).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '-=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider4).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '-=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider5).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '-=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
    },
    //on mouseout
     function() {
      $(this).stop(false, true).animate({
        width: '-=412px' //substracts 250px

        }, 'slow' 
      );
       $(slider2).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '+=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider3).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '+=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider4).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '+=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider5).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '+=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
    }
  );
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#slider2").hover(
    //on mouseover
    function() {
      $(this).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '+=412' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
      $(slider1).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '-=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider3).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '-=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider4).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '-=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider5).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '-=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
    },
    //on mouseout
     function() {
      $(this).stop(false, true).animate({
        width: '-=412px' //substracts 250px

        }, 'slow' 
      );
       $(slider1).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '+=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider3).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '+=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider4).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '+=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider5).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '+=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
    }
  );
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#slider3").hover(
    //on mouseover
    function() {
      $(this).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '+=412' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
      $(slider2).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '-=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider1).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '-=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider4).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '-=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider5).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '-=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
    },
    //on mouseout
     function() {
      $(this).stop(false, true).animate({
        width: '-=412px' //substracts 250px

        }, 'slow' 
      );
       $(slider2).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '+=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider1).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '+=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider4).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '+=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider5).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '+=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
    }
  );
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#slider4").hover(
    //on mouseover
    function() {
      $(this).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '+=412' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
      $(slider2).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '-=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider3).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '-=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider1).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '-=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider5).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '-=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
    },
    //on mouseout
     function() {
      $(this).stop(false, true).animate({
        width: '-=412px' //substracts 250px

        }, 'slow' 
      );
       $(slider2).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '+=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider3).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '+=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider1).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '+=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
        $(slider5).stop(false, true).animate({   
        width: '+=138' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
    }
  );
});
```

here's the jsfiddle too

http://jsfiddle.net/atseros/zajnwuzo/1/

Comment: still no solution...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How is this? I added a class to your HTML

> HTML

`

```
<div id="slider1" class="slider">
</div><!--slider1 end -->
<div id="slider2" class="slider">
</div><!--slider2 end -->
<div id="slider3" class="slider">
</div><!--slider3 end -->
<div id="slider4" class="slider">
</div><!--slider4 end -->
```

`

> jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".slider").hover(
    //on mouseover
    function() {

        $(this).stop(false, true).animate({  
        width: '+=412' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow

      );
    },
    //on mouseout
     function() {
      $(this).stop(false, true).animate({
        width: '-=412px' //substracts 250px

        }, 'slow' 
      );
    }
  );
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zajnwuzo/2/) here not sure if this is what you were going for.

Comment: thnx for the response but its not quite the same effect. on mouse over the total width has to be the same as before, and at the hovered block are added 412px while at the other blocks are substracted 138px.

Comment: Yeah I think the issue is the double loaded animate that is trying to execute on the mouseleave event.